# How to find pivoting element properly while performing quick sort?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scala, sorting, quicksort

I have an array with following elements: `var arr = Array[Int](10,16,8,12,15,6,3,9,5)` which I am trying to sort using quick sort technique.
Below is the code I have written to do the quick sort:

```
object Quick {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var arr   = Array[Int](10,16,8,12,15,6,3,9,5)
    var low   = 0
    var high  = arr.length-1
    quickSort(low, high)
    arr.foreach(println)

    def quickSort(low:Int, high:Int):Unit = {
        if(low<high) {
            var j = partition(low, high)
            quickSort(low, j)
            quickSort(j+1, high)
        }
    }

    def partition(low:Int, high:Int): Int = {
        var pivot = arr(low)
        var i = low
        var j = high
        while(i<j) {
            do {
                i += 1
            } while(arr(i) <= pivot)
            do {
                j -= 1
            } while(arr(j) > pivot)
            if(i<j) swap(i, j)
        }
        swap(i, j)
        j
    }

    def swap(ai:Int, aj:Int): Unit = {
        var tmp = arr(ai)
        arr(ai) = arr(aj)
        arr(aj) = tmp
    }
}
```

}

When I run the code, it breaks at the line: `while(arr(i) <= pivot)` where the index is becoming `9`
I handled that first do while by adding a condition `if(i < arr.length-1) i += 1`
The same is happens in the second do while where the index in the line: `while(arr(j) > pivot)` becomes `-1` there by ending in `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. I handled it by adding a condition: `if(j>0) j-= 1`
The code goes into infinite loop if I add those conditions but I removed them, it results in ArrayOutOfBoundsException with indices: 9 & -1 for low and high respectively.

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: `while`, `do/while`, `var`, functions returning `Unit` (in most cases), etc. are all considered code smells in Scala... I'm not sure about quicksort algorithms but try to solve this problem with the constraints of functions always returning a useful type and not mutating any variables. It'll also make debugging easier as you're not having to keep track of what the value of a mutated variable is at any given time.

Comment: This is true but implementing efficient algorithms may require efficient access to and mutation of data. This might be more difficult with pure function approach

Answer (score 1):

I don't know scala, but the code in the question may run beyond the bounds of (low, high). The partition loops rely on stopping for elements == pivot to prevent this. Fixes noted in comments:

```
        var pivot = arr(low)           // any but arr(high)
        var i = low-1                  // fix
        var j = high+1                 // fix
        while(i<j) {
            do {
                i += 1
            } while(arr(i) < pivot)    // fix (not <=) 
            do {
                j -= 1
            } while(arr(j) > pivot)
            if(i<j) swap(i, j)
        }
                                       // fix (no post loop swap)
        j
    }
```

you might consider a slight change (could improve performance). Note the only way out of the while(true) is the return j.

```
        var pivot = arr(low)
        var i = low-1
        var j = high+1
        while(true) {
            do {
                i += 1
            } while(arr(i) < pivot)
            do {
                j -= 1
            } while(arr(j) > pivot)
            if(i >= j) return j
            swap(i, j)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code in partition was too complicate.
Correct example:

```
def partition(low:Int, high:Int): Int = {
  val pivot = arr(high)
  var i = low - 1
  var j = low
  while (j <= high - 1) {
    if (arr(j) < pivot) {
      i += 1
      swap(i, j)
    }
    j += 1
  }
  swap(i + 1, high)
  i + 1
}

def quickSort(low:Int, high:Int):Unit = {
  if(low<high) {
    val j = partition(low, high)
    quickSort(low, j - 1)
    quickSort(j+1, high)
  }
}
```

rest code same.
Algo from: [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)

Comment: Understand that. I tried to find the pivot value by moving the indices of the array first and see if it can work. Thats the reason it looks a bit lengthy.